# how to Update a column with specific values found in any of the rows

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

My query return below results, whenever i see value "YES" for COLUMN4 values i need to Set the "YES" value for all the records under the COLUMN1 group. 
for Example DAVID has 2 records with NO and YES- but my target state should be "YES" for all rows because he has Value "YES" for atleast one of the records.

QUery Results

```
Column1  Column2 Column3 Column4
=================================
Mary     AA      AAA     YES
Mary     BB      BBB     YES
David    AA      AAA     YES
David    BB      BBB     NO
Clara    AA      AAA     NO
Clara    BB      BBB     NO
```

Requested Target State

```
Column1     Column2       Column3      Column4
================================================
Mary        AA            AAA          YES
Mary        BB            BBB          YES
David       AA            AAA          YES
David       BB            BBB          **YES**
Clara       AA            AAA          NO
Clara       BB            BBB          NO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the Select statement you want,

```
SELECT mt.Column1,mt.Column2,mt.Column3,
(CASE WHEN mt2.cc IS NULL THEN 'NO' ELSE 'YES' END) AS Column4 
FROM mytable mt LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT Column1,COUNT(*) AS cc FROM mytable WHERE Column4 = 'YES' GROUP BY Column1)
AS mt2 ON mt2.Column1 = mt.Column1
```

Result:

```
+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|   Column1   |  Column2    |   Column3   |   Column4   |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|   Mary      |      AA     |     AAA     |      YES    |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|   Mary      |      BB     |     BBB     |      YES    |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|   David     |      AA     |     AAA     |      YES    |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|   David     |      BB     |     BBB     |      YES    |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|   Clara     |      AA     |     AAA     |      NO     |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|   Clara     |      BB     |     BBB     |      NO     |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE my_table m set m.column4='YES' 
WHERE m.column4='NO'
AND exists(
select 1 from my_table mm where mm.column1= m.column1 and mm.column4 = 'YES')
```

Comment: Hello Frank, Thanks for the Quick response. is there a way i can achieve using the Selects, because this will be my select statement that i will be posting into my Data Integration Tool Source Qualifier for further cleansing.

Answer (score 1):

Due to comments:

```
UPDATE my_table m1 set m.column4='YES' 
WHERE m1.column4='NO'
AND m1.column1  IN (
select m2.column1 from my_table m2 where mm.column4 = 'YES')
```